# JQuery cycle for hero images stopped working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-cycle

I had my carousel working perfectly.

Upon editing the `a href`'s it just stopped working which is really strange!

The site I originally found it working from is http://radoorco.dk/.

Any idea why just my small changes broke the script?

Comment: I can't seem to find the JavaScript that would control your slider, which file is it?  Did you copy/paste the html markup? I ask because a typical slider/carousel would add the inline styles to your `#slider > a` elements but that isn't the case here, they are hardcoded.

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure you're missing jquery.cycle, which the site you reference uses.

Comment: @ChrisRockwell: Thanks, I'll take a look at it now. Strange that it would have just gone missing by adjusting the links. Will update this in 10 minutes.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisRockwell!! In the process of adjusting image links I must have removed reference to the scripts. Thank you!